# What's a word that means arbitrary, but doesn't carry a negative connotation?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms, connotation, nuance

I'm looking for a word that describes a choice made without reason, but that has a neutral-to-positive connotation. I had always thought that "arbitrary" is inherently neutral, but in practice I've found most people take it pejoratively regardless of the context.

My idea is to encourage someone to make a choice without encouraging creativity, to relieve the pressure of a decision without discouraging personal intention, i.e. to say that the choice can be meaningful or meaningless. The best I can think of so far is "random" but I'm unsure if the positive meaning is conveyed when written.

Comment: Can you use it in an example sentence

Comment: Capricious? Whimsical? Mercurial?

Comment: Please note: For single-word requests: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED;" See http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info

Comment: Perhaps it’s an ***inconsequential*** decision

Comment: *arbitrary* can be neutral, negative, or positive. Depends on the context, and you have provided none. A priori, it is neutral.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is arbitrary.  I'm not sure why you have a negative connotation with it, but I don't think most American English speakers do.

Comment: Really, not even a down vote, but a vote to delete?

Answer (score 0):

The usage that you want is for a special situation where one has nothing to lose.

A suitable word then, is ***pick***. You can say:

> "*take your **pick***"

[From oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pick):

> ***pick*** NOUN
>
> 1 [IN SINGULAR] An act or the right of selecting something from a
> number of alternatives: *take your **pick*** from our extensive menu; Laura
> should have first ***pick***.

[From TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+your+pick):

> **take your pick**: to choose what you want
>
> We've got tea, coffee, or hot
> chocolate - take your pick.

From [dictionary.cambridge.org](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take-your-pick):

> **take your pick**:​ choose any one you want: You can take your pick of
> any dessert on the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original sentence with arbitrary went something like this...

"Make an arbitrary choice"

I would opt for

> "The choice is yours"

This conveys that neutral to positive effect you were searching for I would say, you are affirming the choice is theirs to make, that's a positive message ; and you are highlighting the fact that there is a choice to be made here.

There is also a sense of almost 'shrugging your shoulders' with this idiom as well and a sense of 'over to you'. I think it suits your situation well.

Answer (score 0):

What about a *free choice* or a *freely-chosen* ....(topic/whatever you have in mind...) ? In the meaning

> Able to be done as one wishes; not under the control of another
>   (Oxford Dict.)

PS: I think you should really provide an example sentence that would give more context.